# Change Font-family in FB like box

Tags: facebook, plugins, fonts, web

is it possible to change the fonts in the Facebook Like Box plugin? If there is a way to do it please tell me.
I'm busy building a website and i must change the fonts in the plugin but i can't

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put 
`data-font="verdana"`
 into this div :
`<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>` ?

Comment: I don't have that div. It's a Joomla module. When i put `data-font="verdana"` into the object it don't work :( . But thanks